# How to reshape a data.frame in R without a loop?

Tags: r, reshape

I have a `data.frame` in R. I need to compare two rows of the data and if they are the same I need to merge the rows and combine the data in one column. I feel like this is a common need when working with R so using `ddply` or some other package should be able to accomplish this task. Below is the data as is, `dat`, and what it should like after some code, `foo.` I’m new with R so any help is greatly appreciated.

Before:

```
 dat <- structure(list(detected_id = c(11, 11, 4), reviewer_name = c("mike", 
"mike", "john"), created_at = c("2016-05-04 10:02:45", "2016-05-04 10:02:45", 
"2016-05-04 10:02:45"), stage = c(2L, 2L, 1L), V7 = c("Detected Organism: Staphylococcus Aureus, Comment: Looks good", 
"Detected Organism: Staphylococcus Aureus, Comment: Note 1", 
"Detected Organism: Human Adenovirus 7, Comment: test")), .Names = c("detected_id", 
"reviewer_name", "created_at", "stage", "V7"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

After:

```
foo <- structure(list(detected_id = c(11L, 4L), reviewer_name = c("mike", 
"john"), created_at = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "5/4/16 10:02", class = "factor"), 
    stage = c(2L, 1L), V7 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("Detected Organism: Human Adenovirus 7, Comment: test", 
    "Detected Organism: Staphylococcus Aureus, Comment: Looks good; Detected Organism: Staphylococcus Aureus, Comment: Note 1"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("detected_id", "reviewer_name", 
"created_at", "stage", "V7"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: quick look]

EDIT:

the solutions below worked for the dataset I provided, however I've found a case where these solutions don't actually work as intended. This is an example of a data.frame that fails. Just a note, the detected_id column is obsolete for me.

```
dat <- structure(list(detected_id = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 4), reviewer_name = c("Mike", 
"Mike", "Mike", "Mike", "John", "John"), created_at = c("2016-05-04 10:02:45", 
"2016-05-04 10:02:45", "2016-05-04 10:02:45", "2016-05-04 10:02:45", 
"2016-05-04 10:02:45", "2016-05-04 10:02:45"), stage = c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), V7 = c("Detected Organism: Staphylococcus Aureus, Comment: Looks good", 
"Detected Organism: Staphylococcus Aureus, Comment: Looks good", 
"Detected Organism: Staphylococcus Aureus, Comment: Note 1", 
"Detected Organism: Staphylococcus Aureus, Comment: Note 1", 
"Detected Organism: Stenotrophomonas Maltophilia, Comment: new note", 
"Detected Organism: Human Adenovirus 7, Comment: test")), .Names = c("detected_id", 
"reviewer_name", "created_at", "stage", "V7"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

SOLUTION: remove the detected_id column before reshaping the data.frame, Thanks @eddi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)[, paste(V7, collapse = "; ")
           , by = .(detected_id, reviewer_name, created_at, stage)]
#   detected_id reviewer_name          created_at stage
#1:          11          mike 2016-05-04 10:02:45     2
#2:           4          john 2016-05-04 10:02:45     1
#                                                                                                                         V1
#1: Detected Organism: Staphylococcus Aureus, Comment: Looks good; Detected Organism: Staphylococcus Aureus, Comment: Note 1
#2:                                                                     Detected Organism: Human Adenovirus 7, Comment: test
```

Comment: good solution, works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: check out the edit I made

Comment: @webDevleoper101 I'm not sure what "failed" means to you. It works exactly as expected. A little unclear what you were hoping for - perhaps you want to take `detected_id` out of the `by`.

Comment: OK, your right.. I just removed the 'detected_id' column and than ran the code and it works as expected.. Thanks!

Comment: np, glad that worked

Answer (score 0):

using base R

```
with(dat, aggregate(V7,list(detected_id=detected_id, reviewer_name=reviewer_name, created_at=created_at, stage=stage),paste,collapse=' '))
```

Comment: I like your solution better, as it's just base R, please check the the edit I just made